# How to draw a table with this style?

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts

[image]

Table style as above.

The leftmost column headings are k, n.

The row data for n is from `Range[1, 17]`,

and the row data for k is from `Table[Floor [Log [2, n]+1], {n, 1, 17}]`

Why is the following code not drawn?

```
Grid[{{k, 
   Range[1, 10], {n, Table[Floor[Log[2, n] + 1], {n, 1, 10}]}}},
  Frame -> All]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
tables = Partition[Range @ 17, 9, 9, {1, 1}, {}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 
>  {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}}
> ```

```
toGrid = Map[Grid[#, Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> {2, 1}] &]@
    PadRight[Transpose[{Prepend["n"] /@ #, 
       Prepend["k"] /@ Floor[Log[2, #] + 1]}],
     Automatic, "⋯"] &;

Column[toGrid @ tables, Spacings -> {0, 1/4}]
```

[image]

Replace  `Range @ 17` with `Range @ 24` to get

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how literal you want to be with the style you display, but here's one approach...

First, let's make this generalizable by giving our system some parameters:

```
funcs = <|Style["n", Italic] -> Identity, Style["k", Italic] -> (Floor[1 + Log2[#]] &)|>;
rowCount = 3; (* in your example this was 2 *)
length = 22; (* in your example this was 17 *)
```

Then, let's generate the data:

```
data = Through[Values[funcs][Range@length]];
```

Now, create the grid:

```
Grid[
  Riffle[
    ArrayPad[
      Riffle @@ Transpose[Normal[Multicolumn[#, rowCount] & /@ data], {1, 3, 2}] /. Null -> \[Ellipsis],
      {{0, 0}, {1, 0}},
      List /@ Keys[funcs]],
    {{Null, SpanFromLeft}},
  1 + Length[funcs]],
Dividers -> All,
ItemSize -> {3, {{3, 3, .5}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

- I can not find an easy way to show a narrow blank lines,here we draw two blank lines `{"", SpanFromLeft}`,`{"", SpanFromLeft}` and remove the `Dividers` between them. We show this method as below.

```
Grid[{{n, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {k, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
   4}, {Item["", Background -> Blue], 
   SpanFromLeft}, {Item["", Background -> Cyan], SpanFromLeft}, {n, 
   10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, "..."}, {k, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5,
    "..."}}, 
 Dividers -> {All, {All, 4 -> Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[5], Red}}},
  Spacings -> {1, {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1}}]
```

[image]

- When we set the `Spacings` to `-2.5`, we get

```
Grid[{{n, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {k, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
   4}, {"", SpanFromLeft}, {"", SpanFromLeft}, {n, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, "..."}, {k, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, "..."}}, 
 Dividers -> {All, {All, 4 -> False}}, 
 Spacings -> {1, {1, 1, 1, -2.5, 1, 1, 1}}]
```

[image]